# rake cucumber hook doesn't work

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, selenium-webdriver

every one

I am new with cucumber & rake in ruby. I have completed a example of cucumber test. My test run ok in Ruby Mine by jetbrain (well, hook Before & After work well). When I try to using Cucumber rake task to start cucumber, the cucumber start and run well except the hook script. I found that both Before and After hook (and another hook) doesn't call when rake run the cucumber job

```
require 'cucumber'
require 'cucumber/rake/task'
require 'rubygems'
require 'rake'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/features/support/selenum_drivers"

task :features => [:chrome_runner]
Cucumber::Rake::Task.new (:chrome_runner) do |t|
  SeleniumCommon.configure do |config|
    config.selenium_chrome = true
  end
  t.cucumber_opts = "config=chrome features -f pretty -f progress -r features/all_features -r features/step_definitions"
end
```

Here is my Rake

Any idea for this.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the `cucumber.yml` for the `cucumber_opts`, and placing the other configuration in a `support` file.

[Here a gist I use for javascript, chrome, headless and more.](https://gist.github.com/rosskevin/5937888)